# How to increase or decrease counter using horizontally scrolling button

Tags: android, counter

I am creating one android application in which I want add one horizontally scrolling button to increase/decrease the counter.

For instance if the user scrolls the button towards right, the counter should increase by 1 and scrolling left will decrease the counter by 1.

Please tell me what should I do to accomplish the task. Have a look at the attached image which has the function I want.

I want the counter to increase only when the user scrolls that particular button and not when he swipes somewhere else on the screen

[image]

Comment: Could you show your code? What are u using as one horizontally scrolling button? A Button? A SeekBar?

Comment: @Adri I am not sure how would I go. That's why I am asking for help from professionals to tell what would be the correct way to do this.

Comment: Ok, I'll build a piece of code what you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SeekBar` to increase or decrease the counter. An simple example of a layout you can use might be this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the code woul be this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Selects the TextView which holds the value of the counter
        this.counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        // Sets the initial value of the SeekBar (it must be the same initial
        // value of the counter)
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        // Sets the max value of the counter
        seekBar.setMax(100);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
            // This code runs when you scroll the SeekBar to left or right.
            // If you scroll to the left, the counter decreases and if you
            // scroll to the right, the counter increases
            counter.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: thank you very much for sparing your time to write this code. I currently have this thing in the application but it looks a bit boring. So I decided to add which looks nice and fun, hence I would something like horizontal scroll thing(or button or whatever) to make the UI look nice. For example we tune the radio using the circular horizontally scrolling control. I want to make it like that.